# Bootstrap4: Move/Add elements to my navbar on user scroll

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I have a wordpress site with the front-end developed using bootstrap 4.5 (my first time using bootstrap). The site currently uses the standard, sticky Bootstrap 4 navbar as per code below:

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-dark box-shadow fixed-top">
        
        <a href="https://www.explorecinema.com" class="navbar-brand">
            <h1 class="text-uppercase site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
        </a>

        <p class="navbar-text site-description mb-0">
            <?php 
                $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
                echo $description; 
            ?>
        </p>

        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarCollapse" style="">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
          
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="https://www.explorecinema.com/about-us/" class="nav-link navbar-right"> About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="https://www.explorecinema.com/suggest-content/" class="navbar-link btn btn-outline-success">Suggest Content</a>
            </li>
          </ul>  
          </form>       
        </div>

        
    </nav>
</header>
```

That produces this style of navbar, by default my page title and filters are positioned in my main container below the navbar.

[image]

On scroll however I want to move (or hide and add) the page title and filters into my navbar. To look similar to my rough mock-up below.

[image]

How would I do this, I'm presuming JQuery/Javascript is involved? I've not done something similar before.

My guess is somehow hiding the default header and filters and adding them to the navbar as hidden elements which then get displayed as visible on scroll. If I do this though how would I keep the navbar responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements an be on the navbar, only hidden... you can unhide them when the user scrolls; we need scroll event listener for this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrollingNow = (e) => {
    if (window.scrollY > 50) {
      if ($('#toggleOnScroll').hasClass('hideHeading')) {
        $('#toggleOnScroll').removeClass('hideHeading')
        $('#toggleOnScroll').addClass('showHeading')
      }
    } else {
      if ($('#toggleOnScroll').hasClass('showHeading')) {
        $('#toggleOnScroll').removeClass('showHeading')
        $('#toggleOnScroll').addClass('hideHeading')
      }
    }
  }
  console.log('$ works');
  window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollingNow);
});
```

```css
.hideHeading {
  display: none
}

.showHeading {
  display: block;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-dark box-shadow fixed-top">
    <h2 id='toggleOnScroll' class='hideHeading'>Show Me on Scroll</h2>

    <a href="https://www.explorecinema.com" class="navbar-brand">
      <h1 class="text-uppercase site-title">
        <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
      </h1>
    </a>

    <p class="navbar-text site-description mb-0">
      <?php 
                $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
                echo $description; 
            ?>
    </p>

    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarCollapse" style="">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="https://www.explorecinema.com/about-us/" class="nav-link navbar-right"> About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="https://www.explorecinema.com/suggest-content/" class="navbar-link btn btn-outline-success">Suggest Content</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some
text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/>this
is some text <br/><br/><br/> this is some text <br/><br/><br/>
```